# @Pattern annotation is not working in junit 4

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit

I'm working on a sample spring boot application that performs CRUD operations for the user.

I created a user API. `UsersController.java` is the controller code.

**UsersController.java**

```
    @PostMapping(value = "/users", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, headers = "Authorization")
    @ApiOperation(value = "API endpoint to save users", notes = "API endpoint to save users")
    @ApiResponses(value = {
        @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = ErrorConstants.OK),
        @ApiResponse(code = 400, message = ErrorConstants.BAD_REQUEST),
        @ApiResponse(code = 403, message = ErrorConstants.FORBIDDEN),
        @ApiResponse(code = 500, message = ErrorConstants.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR) }
    )
    public ResponseEntity<?> addUsers(@Valid @RequestBody UserDto userDto) {
        try {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(userService.createUsers(userDto), HttpStatus.OK);
        } catch (BadRequestException e) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
    }
```

DTO is as below

**UserDto.java**

```
    @JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
    public class UserDto {
    
        private String id;
    
        @Size(min = 4, max = 36, message = "Name should be between 4 to 36 characters long.")
        @Pattern(regexp = "^[^&+;=#<>*{}@:]*$", message = "Name field Should not contain special chars")
        private String name;
    
        private String address;
        
        private String mobileNo;
    }
```

As you can see, I've added validation to the `name` field. In addition, I created a controller advise to handle the exception.

**ExceptionControllerAdvise.java**

```
    import org.springframework.web.bind.MethodArgumentNotValidException;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler;
    
    
    @RestControllerAdvice
    public class ExceptionControllerAdvise {
    
        @ExceptionHandler(value = MethodArgumentNotValidException.class)
        public ResponseEntity<ErrorResponse> validException(MethodArgumentNotValidException exception) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }
    }
```

If any validation exceptions are raised for the annotated fields, the above class will return an error.

When I run the application and call the API with an invalid name (one that contains special characters), I get a 400 bad request exception.

But when I try to write junit test case for invalid data, the test case is passing. (i.e. `@Pattern` annotation is not working with junit)

Here is my sample junit for testing.

```
    @Test
    public void test0_createUsersWithInvalidName() {
        UserDto dto = new UserDto();
        dto.setName("Apple&sons!")
        dto.setAddress("abc");
        ResponseEntity<?> response = usersController.addUsers(dto)
        assertTrue(response.getStatusCode().equals(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST));
    }
```

The above test case passes, but I receive a `java.lang.AssertionError` error; when I debugged this issue, I discovered that I am receiving a status of `200 OK` rather than `400 BAD REQUEST`.

So, could anyone please assist me here? Thanks

Comment: Just 2 cents: you should not exclude unwanted but rather allow only wanted characters. Whitelisting is definitely the better way.

Comment: are java (-ae / -enableassertions) assertions on ?

Comment: In this case, if I have to add other language name (ex, Japanese, Chinese) then it will consider special character. That's why excluded characters that are not supported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to test your `bean validation` rules into your controller you can do it by mocking the exception that will happen in your service class or in your integration test by the simulation of a wrong value. Also you can improve the code in your `controller`. Here you are returning a `BAD_REQUEST` in the `catch` section, it is the role of your `ControllerAdvice` class. Instead you should throw a `BadRequestException` request exception that will be transmitted to your `ControllerAdvice`.

*Controller*

```
@PostMapping(value = "/users", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, headers = "Authorization")
@ApiOperation(value = "API endpoint to save users", notes = "API endpoint to save users")
@ApiResponses(value = {
    @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = ErrorConstants.OK),
    @ApiResponse(code = 400, message = ErrorConstants.BAD_REQUEST),
    @ApiResponse(code = 403, message = ErrorConstants.FORBIDDEN),
    @ApiResponse(code = 500, message = ErrorConstants.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR) }
)
public ResponseEntity<?> addUsers(@Valid @RequestBody UserDto userDto) {
    try {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(userService.createUsers(userDto), HttpStatus.OK);
    } catch (MethodArgumentNotValidException e) {
        throw new BadRequestException("YOUR MESSAGE", e); // the e in parameter to get the root cause if you send message from your validation
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new InternalServerErrorException("YOUR MESSAGE", e); // the e in parameter to get the root cause
    }
}
```

*Controller Advice*

```
@RestControllerAdvice
public class ExceptionControllerAdvise {

    @ExceptionHandler(value = BadRequestException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<ErrorResponse> validException(BadRequestException exception) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(value = InternalServerErrorException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<ErrorResponse> serverException(InternalServerErrorExceptionexception) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
}
```

*Test class*

```
@Test
public void test0_createUsersWithInvalidName() {
   
    ...
    
    when(userService
    .createUsers(userDto))
    .thenThrow(MethodArgumentNotValidException.class);

   ...
   // Here use mockMvc instead
}
```

This part of your test code will be used in your integration test:

```
UserDto dto = new UserDto();
dto.setName("Apple&sons!")
dto.setAddress("abc");
```

Also, how do you construct your `ErrorResponse`?

Comment: I agree with you, but have one remark - mocking is for unit testing, because you can afford turning off parts of the code via mocking (i.e. to avoid spinning up a database you can make a method return a result of some kind). Integration tests, on the other side, cannot use the mocking approach, because by definition it is an end-to-end kind of test (which is why it also takes much longer)